# bug in overpic with abs and unit?

Tags: overpic

The following code works absolutely fine:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=\maxdimen]{standalone}
\usepackage{overpic} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \fbox{\begin{overpic}[unit=30mm]{example-grid-100x100bp.jpg}
    \end{overpic}}%
    \fbox{\begin{overpic}{example-grid-100x100bp.jpg}
    \end{overpic}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and gives the following image:

[image]

However, when I simply change
`\usepackage{overpic}` to `\usepackage[abs]{overpic}`, or
`\begin{overpic}[scale=0.02, unit=30mm]{example-grid-100x100bp.jpg}` to `\begin{overpic}[abs, scale=0.02, unit=10mm]{example-grid-100x100bp.jpg}`, I get:

[image]

So basically the second image is now overlapping on the first.
I would have expected the 2 images to simply be side to side, instead of overlapping as in the second image. I would have expected that setting `unit` to some value should not change the position of the plot, but it does.
Is this a bug, or am I misunderstanding something?

My main use case of `\overpic` is that it allows to put text on the graphics, for example like this:

```
\begin{figure}
    \fbox{\begin{overpic}[abs, unit=30mm]{example-grid-100x100bp.jpg}
    \put(0.5, 0.5){hello}
    \end{overpic}}%
    \fbox{\begin{overpic}{example-grid-100x100bp.jpg}
    \end{overpic}}
\end{figure}
```

which gives me:

[image]

EDIT: as suggested in comments, I added a `\fbox` around the `\overpic` to show that overpic seems to think that the figure is now smaller.

Seems to be related to this question:[overpic overlap box frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232064/overpic-overlap-box-frame)

(image from here:http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mwe/example-grid-100x100bp.jpg)

Comment: Please use an image that others have access to, for example one of the images listed in https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mwe

Comment: Perhaps you should also explain exactly what outcome you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the post as you suggested. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: If you use `\fbox{\begin{overpic}....\end{overpic}}` you can see that the size of the first image (under `abs`) if smaller than the actual image and this it appears to be overlapping

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So by setting `[abs, unit=30mm]` (which should just set the unit and the positional option), makes overpic believe that the image is now smaller than what is actually is? That doesn't sound right

Comment: overpic uses counters to set the picture size and this are integers. With a large unitlength (10mm or 30mm in your examples) you get a quite drastic rounding errors. Imho overpic could avoid that as a current picture environment allows the use of dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to NOT put abs anywhere and specify the units directly inside the `\put` command:

```
\begin{figure}
    \fbox{\begin{overpic}{example-grid-100x100bp.jpg}
    \put(15mm, 15mm){hello}
    \end{overpic}}%
    \fbox{\begin{overpic}{example-grid-100x100bp.jpg}
    \end{overpic}}
\end{figure}
```

which then gives the wanted result:

[image]

Comment: I don't see a `\put` in OP's code.  Could you elaborate on how this solve the problem?  Could you create a MWE, similar to OP's code?

Comment: see update in the question and in the answer